# Can't use WinRM client from specific server

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-command, winrm

I'm trying to use invoke-command from a Windows 2019 server (server A) to another Windows server (server B). I know WinRM is configured on server B because I am able to successfully use invoke-command from my workstation to server B. However when I try the same exact command with the same credentials from server A to server B it fails with the below error message. It fails so quickly that it seems like it's not even trying to reach out over the network.

[image]

Things I have tried so far:

1. Set trusted hosts on both servers using `winrm s winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}`
2. Did a packet trace on our router to ensure packets on 5985 were allowed
3. Disabled the firewall on server A
4. Ran "winrm quickconfig" on both servers

The command I'm using to test is `invoke-command -computername "server B" {1}`.
I'm able to successfully ping server B from server A.

Any thoughts on what could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Depending upon what you need to run, you could also try:   Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $computerName -Path win32_process -Name Create -ArgumentList "your.exe /yourargs".  If not, have you read this? https://vikas15bhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/enable-powershell-remoting/

Comment: Unfortunately I need all of WinRM to work because a 3rd party tool is trying to use it. I tried the steps in the article to no avail.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Are they both on the same domain?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Yes, they are on the same domain